# aiohttp session.post() sends a file with an unreadable name

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

I send a file to Telegram chat using `aiohttp.FormData()`

```py
bytes_io = BytesIO(b"test file content 1")
file_content = bytes_io.getvalue()

file_name = "тест_1.txt"

async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    post_file_data = aiohttp.FormData()
    post_file_data.add_field(
        "chat_id", json.dumps(chat_id),
        content_type='application/json'
    )
    post_file_data.add_field(
        "document", file_content, filename=file_name,
    )
    response = await session.post(
        url_doc, proxy=full_proxy_url, ssl=False,
        data=post_file_data,
    )
```

Everything works, but the file name can only be of ASCII characters.
Otherwise the file name becomes unreadable (for example: "%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82_1.txt").

How can I make the file name display normally for any characters?

Comment: We have no idea what `file_name` contains or how it's wrong. Can you please [edit] to show us those parts (and probably remove the irrelevant parts, to produce a [mre])?

Answer (score 2):

The issue has been resolved. It should be done like this:

```py
    post_file_data = FormData(quote_fields=False)
    ...
```